# Animate an array of objects in React Native

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

In React, it seems like an animation is always bound to a property in `this.state`. But what if I have multiple objects in a view that need to be animated? For example what if I have a ListView with multiple Images and I want to animate the opacity of those images as they load into the ListView?

```
render() {
  //var _scrollView: ScrollView;
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView
        style={styles.scrollView}>

        <ListView
            initialListSize={1}
            dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
            renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}
            style={styles.postList}
            />

      </ScrollView>

    </View>
  );
}

renderRow(post) {
  //var postItemHeight = windowSize / 2
  return (
    <View style={styles.postItem}>
      <Image
        style={styles.postImage}
        source={{uri: post.cover_image}}
        onLoad={(e) => this.imageLoaded()}>

      </Image>
    </View>
  );
}

imageLoaded() {
  // now animate the image opacity
  // for every image that is loaded into the listview
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how you are animating your components. With css, I presume?

Comment: @Chris well I don't know what is the best way, that's why I'm here. opacity is technically a css property but not sure if that helps. I was thinking to use Animations https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animations.html

Comment: If you're just "animating" the opacity of a component, I imagine just changing the css would be easier. Though, I am not familiar with what you just linked and don't know how viable it is. So, you just want to make the opacity of a component gradually change over a short time, rather than instantly. Correct? I can provide a css solution if you want.

Comment: @Chris no, animating one property is easy I already know how to do that. I want to do it to an array of objects.

Comment: What prevents you from doing the same thing on more than one component? You can still do that with css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason the `Animated` value needs to live in component state - that's just how the examples show how to do it. If you wanted, you can keep an array of `Animated` values in the state, put them in your Flux store, or however you want to do it.

In your particular case, however, the easiest solution would be create a component that represents a single image row of your `ListView`. You can then use *that* component's individual state to manage its animation.

For example:

```
const FadeImage = React.createClass({
  displayName: 'FadeImage',
  propTypes: Image.propTypes,
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      opacity: new Animated.Value(0)
    };
  },
  setNativeProps(nativeProps) {
    this._image.setNativeProps(nativeProps);
  },
  fadeIn() {
    Animated.spring(this.state.opacity, {
      toValue: 1,
      friction: 10,
      tension: 60
    }).start();
  },
  render() {
    return (
      <Animated.View style={{opacity: this.state.opacity}}>
        <Image {...this.props} onLoad={this.fadeIn} ref={component => this._image = component} />
      </Animated.View>
    );
  }
});
```

It's a drop-in replacement for `Image`, so you can use it just as you would a regular Image component.

Comment: very helpful, especially the Animated.View and adding new Animated.Value(x) thanks a lot @jevakallio.

Comment: That sounds good, to have the animated as a sub component. In my case, I face another problem, when the parent component updates its state and re-renders everything including the animated sub-components, the animations start from the beginning, which makes sense why, but how would I avoid that? I would like my animations to finish and be uninterrupted, even if parent component re-renders. Not sure how clear I've been xD

Comment: @CatalinBerta sounds like a new question to me :) - but if you've `key`ed your existing elements correctly, they shouldn't be remounted, and the animations should continue uninterrupted.